# PHP Class that handles all includes / required files

Tags: php, object-oriented

In effort to streamline applicable PHP file `include` or `require` functions I thought that making a class to handle this might be a good idea.

Originally I had an `includes/init.php` file that included everything, I wanted to make this more dynamic to the specific page the user was on. For example, some pages require the Google maps script or custom `Javascript` that other pages don't need.

Here is a quick simplified example that doesn't address the dynamic `include` declarations yet:

```
class JIncludes {
    public function getClasses() {
        foreach (glob("includes/classes/*.php") as $filename) {
            require_once($filename);
        }
    }

    public function getCoreTop() {
        require_once('includes/core/head.php');
        require_once('includes/core/header.php');
    }

    public function getCoreBottom() {
        require_once('includes/core/footer.php');
    }
}
```

Is this even a good idea? Will creating this Class object cause more overhead then the alternative?

I have tested this with the following in my `index.php`:

```
$include = new JIncludes();
$include->getClasses();
$include->getCoreTop();

$db = new DB('local');
$db->prepare('String');
```

The source shows the html from my `head.php` file fine and my `PDO` `DB` class works as well. Am I over-complicating things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mixing

You are mixing 2 things:

- class loading
- "template" loading

You aren't over complicating things - you try to over simplify them.

### Class loading

In your solution you are loading all classes if only (for example) 2 of them required to serve the request the loading of the other 52321 class is just a waste of time and resources.

Read about automatic class loading: [Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

With this feature in your mind you can create a custom logic to load the necessary classes (name resolution, class location in file system etc.).

### Template

The other thing what you want is loading your templates into the rendering process. This is hard to do it right, all depends on your "framework" solutions for example naming conventions, is your app frame an MVC based stuff etc.

Answer (score 2):

What you may not know, is that class loading, mostly, already has several [well established solutions](http://www.mwop.net/blog/245-Autoloading-Benchmarks.html).

First and foremost, PHP supports, as of version 5, [Class auto loading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php). (There's still no (planned) function auto loading unfortunately.)

Fundamentally, when a class is instantiated that doesn't already exist, PHP executes the [`__autoload()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) magic function, allowing it to `include`/`require` the class' file as necessary.

As so often, compared to having a manually written, hand-tuned and very precise include/require strategy, there's will be a negative performance impact.

However, compared to "just include everything on every run", an autoloader is a big performance benefit, as you then only pull into memory exactly the classes that you need.

My recommendation for solution, is *not* to implement `__autoload`, but rather stick with [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) loading. PSR-0 is an autoloading standard used by a [large number of large projects](http://www.php-fig.org/). For the vast majority of use-cases, it's "good enough".

Using PSR-0 means you can also autoload any of the classes from other projects that use the standard, which makes interoperability much, much, easier.